# Template ID for Docusign Gen for Salesforce

Tags: docusignapi

How do I get the template id for a template created with Docusign Gen for Salesforce? The Template Id field is empty for any active template that I create.

Comment: can you log in to your DocuSign account directly? by going to www.docusign.net and logging in? if you can find your template in there - you can find its ID easily...

Comment: My Docusign Gen templates do not show up in my Docusign account when I sign in via docusign.net. Anyways, the template id started showing up on salesforce after few refreshes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is probably just a delay issue and if you wait a few minutes and refresh the page - you'll see the template in Salesforce and can find the ID.